# How to run Android Junit Test from inside my java application

Tags: java, junit, activityunittestcase

I want to run my android junit test case from my java class. Can I do that using **JUnitCore** class **run** method or is there some other way possible.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this?  If so, why?

Comment: Hi Charlesworth , I am creating a test application in java which has a mobile testing module as well. I read the test cases from an excel and then execute the same from my java class by calling the junit test and then write the result obtained from my test class(whether the test passed or failed) back in my excel